# Can't instantiate .net object in vba

Tags: .net, vb.net, vba, com, instantiation

I created a class library project in visual studio express 2010, vb.net.

I checked Project / Application / Assembly Information / Make assembly COM-Visible.

I built the project.

I copied myproject.dll and myproject.tlb to C:\WINNT\system32

I ran C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe myproject.dll /codebase. (I get "warning RA0000", but then "Types Registered successfully".)

I look in regedit, and I find keys for my classes in HKEY_Classes_Root/CLSID and /classname and /TypeLib.

In Excel in the VBA editor, I go to Tools/References, and add a Reference to the tlb file in the system32 folder. (The reference does not appear in the References folder in the project manager.)

In VBA, I write:

```
Dim y as string
Dim x as myproject.myobject
set x = New myproject.myobject
y = x.testfunction(Input:="Hi")
```

Intellisense recognizes myproject, and after typing my project it also prompts all my class names. And on the method call, both the method name and parameter name are automatically capitalized.

When I step through the code, at

```
set x = New myproject.myobject
```

I get error: Run-time error'-2146233065 (80131517)':   Automation error

If I declare x as Variant instead, with some of my classes I can instantiate and access members. With others I get the same error.

I also tried the hack with Excel.exe.config file, and .net version, in the excel application folder.

Can anyone help? Sorry this is my first time compiling an add-in, and I think it must be simple. But there's not a lot of guidance or clarity in the process, it seems to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I did not have the “Register for COM Interop” setting in VSE. So I followed a tip to look in the .vbproj file, and add the line "<RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>" after any "<NoWarn>" lines. I forgot if the suggested lines were there already, or I added them--but they are there now.

Comment: It seems like my problem may have to do with constructors. Of my three classes, for two I wrote no constructor. For the third I wrote a constructor that did a lot of stuff with both variables scoped to the procedure and with class scope private variables. I added empty public constructors to the first two, and now the seem to work (at least as far as instantiation). Now I'll try trimming down or emptying the third constructor. (I think my first partial success with Variant type may be b/c I made those constructors before that.)

Comment: VBA doesn't support constructors with parameters so yeah you definitely do need them default constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see so far, as far as merely instantiating an object from a vb.net addin in vba goes, is:

1. You must explicitly declare the class constructor (Sub New()))--can't let vb.net mange it implicitly.
2. The constructor can not be Private (so I think this interferes with the static and singleton class patterns).
3. The constructor can not take arguments (as mentioned in the comment, thanks).
4. The constructor can't do "too much". I haven't yet figured out what too much is.

My constructor code was copied over and translated from VBA. There were no arguments, of course. And it worked fine. There were some private class-level dictionaries instantiated (which lay behind properties). Some default elements were added to those dictionaries via calls to the class's Let Properties. Maybe calling the properties was going too far. At first I suspected that I could not have any code at all in the constructors. But that's not it. I've tested having code, referencing variables local to the constructor and private to the class. But only value types so far. I guess I should have waited to try to sniff out the exact breaking point in constructor functionality, before answering--but I'm getting tired of rebuilding and restarting, and need to get on with a rough working draft for the moment.

I'm sure vb.net constructors, in the context of .net alone, can do everything a vba constructor can and more. It seems that somehow in the interplay of .net and com and vba, that there is some hitch. I haven't found any discussion of this issue online. So maybe instead it's just a bug in my system. Or maybe most people use c# not vb, and c# works better. Or--I don't know.

Comment: Or I may just have an error in that constructor code--an error that gets past the debugger.

Comment: Well, I think I now understand the issue with my hiccup #4 above: The one constructor I originally had that was declared, was public, and didn't take parameters--did call properties which properties were declared with parameters (the parameters being several optional string inputs that could be combined in different ways to make the index for the internal private dictionary that held the input). I guess since C# doesn't allow parameters in properties--my vb.net add in can't either. Why even allow vb.net for an add in if you can't use its syntax then??!! (Note VBA allows params in proptys...)

Comment: More in the vein of using vb.net, but not!: If I want to have a class that contains functions (wrappers for an external dll) and never retains data, then in C# I would declare that Static, yes? VB.net does not have Static. But it is suggested that in vb.net 1. Not inheritable, plus 2. All methods Shared, plus 3. Private constructor is equivlanet. Oh wait: I can't do #3. Ok, I've also seen is said that the easier equivalence to a Static class is just a module. Great! Except it looks like I can't expose modules in the COM add in. Just classes. Again: why even allow vb.net then???

Comment: Does no one use vb.net for excel com add ins? I've seen no discussion of any of this. But I'd expect that lots of people would have tried to move from vba to vb.net, more than to c#??